# Prevent all JS events inside <iframe>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an `<iframe>` in my site, but I want the site that I am displaying to only be scrollable. All other events should be disabled.

So that the container of the `<iframe>`, the `<iframe>` has a width and height of 100%, behaves as if it has nothing inside it.

Almost like it is a scrollable screenshot of the site. So on hover and on click inside the `<iframe>` don't work.

The reason I am doing this is that the container of the `<iframe>` needs to be draggable, but can't be dragged as all events on the `<iframe>` are being registered within the `<iframe>`.

How can I do this in javascript and / or jQuery?

Can I apply a `.preventDefault()` to everything except scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could overlay a `div` with `opacity: 0` (meaning it's fully transparent). That div will intercept most events, such as `onclick`.

You can then add a `mousedown` listener to that `div` which will initiate the 'drag'. The iframe then moves with the transparent `div`.

This will also disable scrolling though, but maybe you can mirror a scroll event from the div to the iframe .. will be tricky.

Comment: So the html markup structure is looking like `<div id="window"><ifram src="somewebsite.com"><p>Browser doesn't support iframes.</p></iframe><div id="overlay"></div></div>` Does that look good? Do I then bind the drag event to the #overlay or to the #window?

Comment: The overlay doesn't show even though it is after the `<iframe>` and has a higher z-index. Right now it has a coral background and no opacity. Here it is: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcT0pIdGRmcjB5NkE/tabView.html Click on the link to show the `<iframe>`

Comment: The overlay doesn't show because you `tabViewWindow` has no dimensions. Set a width and a height.

Comment: Yes it does. 100% and 100%. It is defined in the CSS, line 13, I believe.

Comment: Also, if supported it has 100vw and 100vh, which are equal to 100% viewport width and 100% viewport height.

Comment: `100%` of nothing is still nothing.

Comment: But, I have given the body a 100% height and since that is the parent of #tabViewWindow, 100% of that 100% is a 100% in terms of height and width.

Comment: I figured it out. It was that the #overlay needed top:0; and absolute to be at the top of the viewport an over the <iframe> instead of below it.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a clear div on top of it, if you can use CSS, set the opacity to zero, and set the `z-index` to 1 on the div, and to -1 on the iframe. Doing that should make the div receive the mousedown events. You could also do `document.getElementById("id").onclick=function(){}` and make nothing happen on them

Comment: You don't need to use `z-index`, just make sure the overlay `div` is defined _after_ the `iframe`.

Comment: So the html markup structure is looking like `<div id="window"><ifram src="somewebsite.com"><p>Browser doesn't support iframes.</p></iframe><div id="overlay"></div></div>` Does that look good? Do I then bind the drag event to the #overlay or to the #window?

Comment: @DjangoJohnson bind the events to the iframe

Comment: @scrblnrd3 But, they won't register because the overlay will be over the iframe. I thought my only choice would be #window or #overlay because those are the highest things and only two clickable / draggable things?

Comment: The overlay doesn't cover the <iframe>, right now it has a coral background and no opacity, and it is not covering even though it is after and has a higher z-index. Click on the link in this page to show it: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcT0pIdGRmcjB5NkE/tabView.html